# Getting "You need to enable Javascript to run this" error while fetching result from an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

express.js

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'doc')));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "10mb", type: "application/json" }));
app.use(cors())

app.use('/search', proxy({
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/search': '/search'
    },
    target:<target API URL>,
    secure: false
}));

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(HTTP_PORT);
```

Axios call

```
  getBacklogItemsData = (query) => {
    const jqlQuery = this.getBacklogItemsJQLQuery(query);
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': "Basic <authString>",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    };
    const auth = {
       username: <id>,
       password: <pass>,
    }
    const proxy = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5000
    };
    let config = {
      headers
    }
    return axios.get(`/search?jql=${jqlQuery}/`, auth, headers, proxy, config);
  }
```

package.json

```
  "proxy": "https://localhost:5000",
  "homepage": ".",
```

Error -
[image: You need to enable JS]

Requested headers -
[image: Req header]

**What have I tried so far?**

1. Direct call to the API with the same requested parameters returns the correct response (using postman and web browser)
2. Added "." as homepage in package.json
3. Added localhost:5000 as proxy in package.json
4. Used corsOption -

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
  }

app.use('/search', cors(corsOptions), proxy({
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/search': '/search'
    },
    target: baseURL,
    secure: false
}), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
  });
```

5. I did a direct axios request to target API and got CORS issue

```
axios.get(`<TargetAPIUrl>/search?jql=${jqlQuery}/`, auth, headers, proxy, config);
```

6. Added proxy parameters to axios.get call as shown above

Comment: And yes javascript is enabled in my chrome browser, I checked. I am getting the same issue in other browsers as well.

Comment: I don't know who's answering these requests, but I have a strong feeling that it ain't your express server.

Comment: That message usually shows up in web pages that have `<noscript>` tags. I'm not sure how it would appear in an API response.

Comment: API response is returning HTML instead of json

Comment: @Thomas I think this is the issue, let me just check. But how did u even realize that

Comment: A server running in nodejs answering with "please turn on JS"? That would be silly, like "knock, knock ... I'm not here". But that was just intuition. I just realized (as you answered to Barmar) that this is the rendered response, not necessarily the literal text in the response body. And that this may be the default page returned when no route matches the request (for whatever reason).

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas for your inputs. This solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the axios.get should be called like this.

```js
axios.get('/api', {
  auth,
  headers,
  proxy
}
```

- https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Answer (score 1):

- Acredito que você precisa nomear os parâmetros ao passar para o método:

```js
const options = {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': "Basic <authString>",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    auth = {
       username: <id>,
       password: <pass>,
    },
    proxy = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5000
    }
 }

axios.get(`<TargetAPIUrl>/search?jql=${jqlQuery}/`, options);
```